# How to change labels in the projects page in wp-admin wordpress?

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, wp-admin

​I want to change labels in this page ex: Client -> Owner What is the file name where I can change these labels from?

screenshot:

https://snag.gy/75oUTb.jpg

I tried to do it by javascript, but it caused effect on all website pages, on previewing, editing or updating, the page turns to white.

This is my piece of code

```
echo "<script type='text/javascript'>

        window.onload = replaceTxt; 

         function replaceTxt() {

         var vr1 = document.getElementById('_bunch_bunch_projects_settings[client]').childNodes[1].childNodes[1].innerHTML;

         var vr11 = vr1.replace('Client','Owner');

}

         </script>";
```

Answer (score 1):

use this code.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function replaceScript() {
var toReplace = 'http://google.com';
var replaceWith ='http://yahoo.com';
document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace(toReplace, 
replaceWith);
}
</script>
```

Then initialize in the body tag to do on page load.

```
<body onload="replaceScript();">
```

I think its work for you.

Comment: There is no a body tag in the post.php file !!